# Implementing TaskQueue on Google-App-Engine with Python 2.7

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, task-queue

I am trying to learn about GAE Task Queues with Python 2.7.  The sample code [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push) doesn't work when I try to copy and past it into a 'helloworld.py' app from the Python 2.7 tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld).

I think it's because I don't have a 'counter.html' and I gather it is a pretty simple task to make one because it says this:

> (In this example, 'counters.html' refers to a Django template that contains the HTML for a page that displays the counter value, and a button to trigger a POST request to the / URL.)

I gather that I should know how to make 'counter.html' but I can't.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is spectacularly unhelpful. If something doesn't work, tell us what _does_ happen, and if there's a stacktrace or other information, include it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to adapt the [guestbook template example](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates) pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is copy/paste from the Google sample page and is not working, then it may be your app.yaml and queue.yaml files are not set up properly. Symptom = your TQ call never gets to the handler. (You do need more specificity re: problem as Nick said.) Reference for yamls:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue